# Wait For AsyncTask to finish before executing script

Tags: java, android, scripting

```
package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

import com.cydeon.plasmamodz.R;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//Class for Boot Animation Blue Kindle
public class Boots extends Activity {

public static String TAG = "Boots";
Process process;

private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sURL) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(sURL[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            //Shows 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            //Download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/TWRP-Blaze-2.4.3.0-1.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                //Publish the Progress
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100/fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Installing. Please Wait";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        try {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process proc = rt.exec("su");

                proc = rt.exec("sh /sdcard/boots.sh");
                InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.boots);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.boot1);
    Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAInstall);
    Button rtrn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAReturn);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Boots.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading..." );
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
            downloadFile.execute("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/t16a0cq0qcon2ux/TWRP-Blaze-2.4.3.0-1.zip");



            }

        }
    );

    rtrn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    }



   }
```

Sorry if I didn't search good enough. I have my code with me so I'll post it. Also, as you can probably see, I have no idea how to include a script in my app and then run it. I tried making a new folder and putting the script in it, but it doesn't work. Help on that would too be appreciated...

Edit: I got the first part to work. Now I cannot execute the script. su is executed, but my script is not. I also need to know where to put my script in my app, and then run that script. I'm not sure where the script will be when you install the app. And I don't know where to put the script. So help would be appreciated. Below(I guess above now.lol) is the updated code:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `onPostExecute` method that you can use for post-execution instructions. His parameter depends on what you specify as an output in the `AsyncTask` definition.

In order to use an output, you need to return something in the `doInBackground` method. A good practice would be to check if this output is null or not before using it. That should do it =)

Comment: Ok. As you saw, I put the script execution in the OnClickListener. Shoud I move it to onPostExecute then?

Comment: Yes, if you move your `Runtime` instructions to `onPostExecute` they will be executed right after `doInBackground` is done.

Comment: Thanks. As for my script, do you know why it won't execute?

Comment: Try calling your script with a more specific syntax instead : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[]). Otherwise, you will need to ensure that the runtime user has sufficient permissions to execute this script. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I got the first part to work. But I still can't get the script to execute. such is executed though. I added an update code. Please take a look at it. Also, I want to include these scripts in my app, so where would I put them? And then what would the directory of the script be when I install it?